# How to use select2 for programmatically created select?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to fill dynamicly created select and initialize select2 library (https://select2.github.io) on it.
I have this html code structure:

```
<div class="form_write">
   <i>Тип кузова</i>
   <select name="" id="" class="marka razdel">
      <option value="">bmw</option>
      <option value="">mers</option>
      <option value="">opel</option>
      <option value="">honda</option>
      <option value="">jiguli</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I programmatically create it:
(don't look at ajax request, response from it is not used)

```
$('.razdel').on('change', function () {
    var thisElem = $(this);
    $.post('/ajax/getSubRazdels', {razdel_id: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
        var razdels = JSON.parse(data);
        var wrapper = $('<div class="form_write"></div>').append('<li></li>');
        var select = $('<select name="" class="marka"></select>');
        wrapper.append(select);
        $(select).select2();
        thisElem.closest('.form_write').after(select);
    });
});
```

Select creates but it's hidden, can't understand what I missed?

Comment: Have you tried after adding an `option`?

Comment: thanks, after additing options the problem resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was because I initialized select2 on select element without options after additing them it works!
Here is the solution:

```
$('.razdel').on('change', function () {
    var thisElem = $(this);
    $.post('/ajax/getSubRazdels', {razdel_id: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
        var razdels = JSON.parse(data);
        var wrapper = $('<div class="form_write"></div>').append('<i></i>');
        var select = $('<select name="" class="marka"></select>');
        $.each(razdels, function (k, v) {
            var option = $('<option></option>').attr('value', v['id']).text(v['title']);
            select.append(option);
        });
        wrapper.append(select);
        $(select).select2();
        thisElem.closest('.form_write').after(wrapper);
        //console.log(thisElem.closest('.form_write').after());
    });
});
```